# Spectral theorem versus diagonalisability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

There are two versions of the spectral theorem that I see in sources (for the real case):

1. For an inner product space $(V,g)$ with a s.a operator $T$, there exists an o.n.b s.t. each basis vector is an eigen-vector of $T$.
2. Given any symmetric matrix $T$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ s.t. $P^{-1}TP$ is diagonal with the diagonal elements of the matrix corresponding to the eigenvalues of $T$.

The second condition is essentially the diagonalisability condition. It is fairly obvious that if one expresses $T$ in an arbitrary basis, then the existence of an o.n.b implies by change of basis the second definition except for one point: $P$ is orthogonal. What am I missing?

Comment: more generally : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: You forgot one thing : your "arbitrary" base has to be orthonormal. Therefore the passage matrix $P$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. So, essentially- as long as the set of transformation matrices of T written in terms of an o.n.b corresponds to the set of symmetric matrices- the argument holds.